# How to get an image to scale vertically inside a table cell?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a legacy table layout, and I've come across a layout problem with the scaling of images within a table cell.

The following code when in a page, scales the image up and down as the width of the browser window changes.  However if you change the browswer height of the window up and down, it doesn't scale the image it seems to be locked to whatever the width of the image is.  So if the window is wide, then the green section disappears off the bottom of the window

How can I make it so it scales based on height as well? Meaning the red section and the green section should squash the image till it is tiny as the height of the browser gets smaller.

There are javascript solutions to this problem, but I'd like to do it with HTML/CSS.

```
      <style>
    .red {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .green {
      background-color: green;
    }

    table {
      height: 100vh;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <col width="100">
    <col width="100%">
    <col width="100">
    <tr class="red" style="height:100px;"> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td></td> </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png" />
      </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green" style="height:200px;">
      <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

so here is the width compressed, and the image shrinks...
[image]

here, the width is wider, but the height is the same, but the image is now taking more vertical height
[image]

Comment: Can you draw the image what you trying to do exactly

Comment: the goal would be like the first image, where the test pattern is small, but the windows would be wider, so the red and green would be as wide as the red in the second image.  I don't mind if the image stretches or doesn't maintain aspect ratio either

Comment: You mean the red and green will be visible in all screen and the image can stretch when browser resize right?

Comment: right, @zer00ne s answer is very close to what I want, other than the the surrounding table cells should be of fixed sizes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those edits will be useful, play with it.

```css
    .red {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .green {
      background-color: green;
    }

    table {
      height: 100vh;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .image{
position: relative;
padding-top: 30vh;

    }
    
    .image img{
       position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: auto;
 max-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 left: 0;
    }
```

```html
 <table style="width:100%">
    <col width="100">
    <col width="100%">
    <col width="100">
    <tr class="red" style="height:100px;"> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td></td> </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td class="image">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png" />
      </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green" style="height:200px;">
      <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I set `max-height` for your image to visible the bottom green section in all devices. So you can resize it. You can adjust the `max-height` based on your requirement. I hope this solution may help you.

```css
 .red {
     background-color: red;
 }
 
 .green {
     background-color: green;
 }
 
 table {
     height: 100vh;
     table-layout: fixed;
 }
 
 img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     max-height: 450px;
     object-fit: contain;
 }
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="100">
            <col width="100%">
                <col width="100">
    </colgroup>
    <tr class="red" style="height:100px;">
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png" />
        </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green" style="height:200px;">
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your `<col>` widths were 100px, 100%, 100px which is 200px over. The middle column is a non-specified width so it takes whatever space the left and right fixed columns do not take.
- The height for the first row is 100px and last row is 200px. The height of the middle row takes up the remaining vertical space. [Special pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) were used to target the `td` (not the `tr`). `tr` seems the logical choice to modify height but it isn't't, because the nature of a html is content oriented therefore witdh and height is 90% `td` and 10% `table`.

  > ```
  >  tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type
  >
  >  tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type
  > ```
- `<html>` and `<body>` are set to 100% x 100% `position:relative` so the `<table>` assigned with `position:absolute` sits squarely within the viewport.
- The middle row was expanded by `colspan='3'` and the image is now a background-image. With a minor change the image can expand and fill the whole row without overflow or shifting the other rows further. set `background-size` to `cover` from `contain`.

---

### Demo

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

table {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) td {background:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png" )no-repeat; background-size:contain;background-position:center center;}

tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type {
  min-height: 100px;
}

tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type {
  min-height: 200px
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <col width="100">
    <col>
    <col width="100">
    <tr class="red">
      <td height='100'> </td> <td>
      </td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3'> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td height='200'> </td>
      <td></td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: the top and bottom rows need to be locked to 100px and 200px, and the left and right need to be locked to 100px, the middle is then allowed to take however much is left

Comment: no, I don't.   The updated code also doesn't do that.  the red and green rows get bigger and smaller, they aren't locked to their pixel size.

Comment: My bad I got you mixed up with another person, check it out.

Comment: seems to still have the same problem as the second image in my question.  As the vertical space shrinks, the image doesn't and the green gets pushed off screen

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @KeithNicholas Nevermind it's ready and will not exceed nor diminish from the viewport edges.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/xhc6ovzL/

```
 <table style="width:100%">
<col width="100">
<col width="100%">
<col width="100">
<tr class="red" style="height:100px;"> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td></td> </tr>
<tr>

  <td colspan="3">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png" />
  </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="green" style="height:200px;">
  <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td>
</tr>
```